# How can I catch a token and an email in a django url?

Tags: python, django, url, path

I am trying to use re_path to catch the following url

```
http://localhost:5000/auth/zzDbEOGxVBzyKMKjfQtNR51VxTVX2p9YvlD5oCiB73Xndj0kD6f8tB6YXNaY/?email=test%40test.se
```

I have tried

```
re_path(r'^auth/(?P<token>\w+)/(?P<email>[\w.@+-]+)/', views.create_update_user, name='auth'),
```

and other permutations but I can't seem to get it right

I was originally trying with email only being separated with the ? (no /)

```
http://localhost:5000/auth/zzDbEOGxVBzyKMKjfQtNR51VxTVX2p9YvlD5oCiB73Xndj0kD6f8tB6YXNaY?email=test%40test.se
```

but I couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: Can you share your views.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the value of email is coming as [url querystring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). You need to get the value like this:

```
email = request.GET.get('email')
```

So URL should look like this:

```
re_path(r'^auth/(?P<token>\w+)/$', views.create_update_user, name='auth'),
```

and view should look like this:

```
def create_update_user(request, token):
    email = request.GET.get('email')
    # rest of the code
```